# EF Core Update and Add in the same save

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

Using dotnet core 3.1 and ef core 3.1.7  ( I just updated and testing out EF Core 3.1.13)

The below code I wrote using LinqPad you can see all it does is updates the CurrentIndicator to "N" then adds a new WorkFlow Record of

```
new WorkFlowQueue{
                CurrentIndicator = "Y",
                WorkFlowQueueId = 2,
                PersonId = f.PersonId
            }
```

This is just a simplified version of my actual code where it actually queries the DB and then updates.
The issue I have is every once in a while a WorkflowQueue CurrentIndicator does not update to "N" but it does add a new WorkflowQueue

What this causes is a Person to be in two different workflow queues. Obviously being in two different queues is not a good idea.
I could understand if this happened on every record but we can go hundreds of updates without issue then seemingly randomly it starts missing the update but does the addition.

BTW this code has worked for since last August with no issue, this issue just started happening in the last couple of weeks.

**EDIT added line for BulkMerge**
The line for _dbContext.BulkMerge(Persons, options=>options.IncludeGraph = true); is for Z.EntityFramework library. I switched to that when I started having this issue so the issue started while I had a simple
_dbContext.SaveChanges;

Additional Change is the line _dbContext.Entry(wfq).State = EntityState.Modified; in the below code

```
 void Main()
{
    List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>() { new Person() { PersonId =1, PersonName="BOB"} };

    Persons.FirstOrDefault( ).WorkFlowQueue.Add( new WorkFlowQueue() {CurrentIndicator ="Y",WorkFlowQueueId = 1, PersonId = 1 } );
    Console.WriteLine(Persons);
    
    foreach(var f in Persons)
    {
        f.WorkFlowQueue.ToList().ForEach(wfq => {
        wfq.CurrentIndicator = "N";
         _dbContext.Entry(wfq).State = EntityState.Modified;
        });
        
        f.WorkFlowQueue.Add(new WorkFlowQueue{
            CurrentIndicator = "Y",
            WorkFlowQueueId = 2,
            PersonId = f.PersonId
        }
        );
    }
    _dbContext.BulkMerge(Persons, options=>options.IncludeGraph = true);


    Console.WriteLine(Persons);
}


public partial class WorkFlowQueue
{
    public int WorkFlowQueueId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentIndicator {get;set;}
    public virtual Person Person {get;set;}
}

public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        WorkFlowQueue = new HashSet<WorkFlowQueue>();
    }
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public string PersonName {get;set;}


    public virtual ICollection<WorkFlowQueue> WorkFlowQueue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `WorkFlowQueueId` auto-generated in database? Also you need to show more realistic code, because how you work with db context (the sequence of operations and the operations itself - loading (eager/explicit/lazy), calling `Add`, `Attach`, `Update` or setting `State`) is essential for proper functioning. And these are changed between EF Core versions w/o keeping backward compatibility, so it's not unlikely the working code to broke after EFC update.

Comment: The update to EFC 3.1.13 I just now upgraded to, I just pushed it to production and hopefully over the next few days it will prove to be the fix but since it is so random I can't say for sure. As for the rest of your comment I will update the post to include more detail